# Scikit-Learn's DPGMM fitting: number of components?

Tags: scipy, statistics, scikit-learn

I'm trying to fit a mixed normal model to some data using scikit-learn's DPGMM algorithm. One of the advantages advertised on [0] is that I don't need to specify the number of components; which is good, because I do not know the number of components in my data. The documentation states that I only need to specify an upper bound. However, it looks very much like that is not true:

```
>>> data = numpy.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = 1.0, size = 1000) 
>>> from sklearn.mixture import DPGMM
>>> d = DPGMM(n_components=5)
>>> d.fit(data.reshape(-1,1))
DPGMM(alpha=1.0, covariance_type='diag', init_params='wmc', min_covar=None,
   n_components=5, n_iter=10, params='wmc', random_state=None, thresh=None,
   tol=0.001, verbose=0)
>>> d.n_components
5
>>> d.means_
array([[-0.02283383],
       [ 0.06259168],
       [ 0.00390097],
       [ 0.02934676],
       [-0.05533165]])
```

As you can see, the fitting reports five components (the upper bound) even for data clearly sampled from just one normal distribution.

Am I doing something wrong? Did I misunderstand something?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Lukas

[0] http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html#dpgmm

Comment: And why do you expect the algorithm to recognize, that one component is enough? This is a hard-problem and the algorithm is kind of a heuristic without strong guarantees. From your link: ```only an upper bound of this number needs to be provided. Note however that the DPMM is not a formal model selection procedure, and thus provides no guarantee on the result.``` The picture [there](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/plot_gmm_sin_001.png) shows you what can happen (depending on alpha: select 1 or 4 components), and that this algorithm has its own tuning-parameter **alpha** controlling this

Comment: I realize that it's a hard problem, and that the algorithm is only a heuristic; however if it _always_ results in the maximum number of clusters, the heuristic is kind of useless? I now tried with an alpha of 10^{-10}, n_iter=1000 and 100000 datapoints drawn from a single normal distribution. I'd assume this to be the "simplest possible problem", and it still results in 10 clusters. In other words: I fail to construct any situation in which the algorithm does _not_ utterly fail, so I currently assume I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: ``np.bincount(d.predict(data.reshape(-1, 1)))`` returns ``array([1000])``. The algorithm correctly assigns all training points to a single mixture component.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had similar doubts about results of this DPGMM implementation. If you check provided [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm.html) you notice that DPGMM always return model with n_components, now the trick is to remove redundant components. This can be done with predict function.

Unfortunately this important pice is hidden in comment in code example.

> # as the DP will not use every component it has access to
>   # unless it needs it, we shouldn't plot the redundant components

Comment: It's still not clear to me given the API how to remove these redundant clusters. The example only uses `plot()`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198251/how-to-properly-remove-redundant-components-for-scikit-learns-dpgmm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at using an improved sklearn solution for this kind of problem, namely a [Bayesian Gaussian Mixture](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html). With this model, the suggested prior number of components must be given, but once trained, the model assigns weightings to each component, which essentially indicate their relevance. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEY4fdfXLp8) is a pretty cool visual demo of BGMM in action.

Once you have experimented with training a few BGMMs on your data, you can get a feel for a sensible estimate to the number of components for your given problem.

Comment: The answer to this related question may provide some code to assist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198251/how-to-properly-remove-redundant-components-for-scikit-learns-dpgmm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Oh, and you are probably wondering what the difference between DPGMM & BGMM is, check here for details: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7623